# How to combine two RDD whith different keys in java Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Suppose I have One RDD of `Tuple2` like below:

```
<session1_w1, <0.2, 2>>, 
<session1_w2, <1.3, 4>>, 
<session1_w3, <0.4, 3>>, 
<session2_w1, <0.5, 2>>, 
<session2_w2, <2.3, 6>>
```

I need to map it to the following RDD, such that the last field is the summation of the last fields of the tuples with the same partial key value e.g. `session1`:

```
2 + 4 + 3 => 9   
2 + 6 => 8
```

So The result that I expect is:

```
<session1_w1, 0.2, 9>, 
<session1_w2, 1.3, 9>, 
<session1_w3, 0.4, 9>, 
<session2_w1, <0.5, 8>>, 
<session2_w2, <2.3, 8>>
```

It is some kind of reduction, but I do not want to lose the original keys.

I can calculate the summation by mapping and then reducing to the following RDD, but then I need to merge this RDD with the first RDD to obtain the result.

```
<session1, 9> <session2, 8>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `groupBy` which preserves the structure of your RDD (but it does not preserve the order, so if you want to save the ordering, you must `zipWithIndex` and later `sortBy` the index).

Otherwise if you have `RDD[(String,(Double,Int))]`:

```
// This should give you an RDD[(Iterative(String,Double),Int)]
val group = myRDD.groupBy(_._1).map(x => (x._2.map(y => (y._1,y._2._1)),
                                          x._2.map(y => y._2._2).reduce(_+_))) 

// This will give you back your RDD of [Summed Int, String, Double] which you can then map.
val result = group.map(x => (x._2,x._1)).flatMapValues(x => x)
```

You can also do a simple `reduceByKey` (without the Double), and later join it back to original RDD such that the original Doubles are preserved.

==========EDIT============

The second join solution simply uses the RDD join. You have your original RDD in the format of `RDD[(String,(Double,Int))]` and I presume you have already obtained your RDD of `[(String,Int)]` where String is session, Int is the sum. The join operation is simply:

```
RDDOriginal.join(RDDwithSum).map(x=>(x._1,x._2._1._1,x._2._2)) // This should give you the Session (String) followed by the Double and the Int (the sum).
```

The join method also does not preserve the order, if you want to keep the order, you will have to do zipWithIndex.

Comment: Thanks, but for your second solution, how can I join two RDDs with different keys? For example, the first one has 'key= session1_w1' and the second one has 'key=session1'

Comment: @Mashaye What is your definition for `join`?

Comment: Normally join is done between Rdds with the same set of keys. My RDDs have different keys as described in the question. Anyway, I used the second solution that GameOfThrows provided and it worked.

Comment: @Mashaye I have edited the answer to include the RDD join solution. Both should work.